# Checking if a map or array is empty in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

How do I check if a map has no keys in Presto? If I have a way to check if an array is empty, I can use the `map_keys` function to determine if the map is empty.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `cardinality` function: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#cardinality

```
select cardinality(array[]) = 0;
 _col0
-------
 true
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 6):

To check array is empty just compare it with `= array[]`.
Example:

```
presto> select (map_keys(map(array[], array[])) = array[]) as is_empty;

 is_empty
----------
 true
(1 row)
```

Likewise, to check if a map is empty just compare it with `= map()`.
Example:

```
presto> select (map(array[], array[]) = map()) as is_empty;

 is_empty
----------
 true
(1 row)
```

Comment: I got `'=' cannot be applied to array(row(value integer)), array(row(VALUE integer))`, do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @LeoJiang how can I reproduce? I tried `select array[cast(row(1) as row(value integer))] = array[];` and it correctly returned `false` (in Presto `master`)

Comment: We might be using a weird version of Presto, I found another solution by casting the map to JSON and then casting it to a string. Thanks.